# Download Docx file from local server machine to client?

Tags: c#, http

In c# I've assigned to write code for download and upload docx file from local server machine to the same local client machine. Let me explain clearly,

For example: If i need to send `docx` file (`C:\sample.docx` ) to client machine into directory(`D:\sample`) using web server(Here using `apache tomcat`) .. Here using `httpwebrequest` & `httpwebresponse` classes..

Is there any possible to find out the solution?
Trying simple client - server application, It’s like a file sharing (Server assign word file to client and then client download that assigned file), I'm done with `sockets-TCP/IP` that’s works really fine. But trying to work out using `http`...

Answer (score 1):

You cound not send something for Server to Client. Client have to request, Server have to respond.

This is a rather simple task. You can just place your file into web site folder (~/sites/mysite/simple.docx), if appache is configured and you requested http://mysite/simple.docx, file would be returned as response.

[WebClient](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.net.webclient%28v=vs.80%29.aspx) class [DownloadFile method](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-US/library/system.net.webclient.downloadfile%28v=VS.80%29.aspx) is very suitable for that.